# Is there a way to find what kind of Floating-point arithmetic is used

Tags: math, floating-point, binary, ieee-754

I have this binary number `11000000110011000001011001111101` which should have this decimal representation `0.0736327171325684`.

Is there a smart way to figure out how to interpret the binary value as the given decimal value?

#### Some background

I have a binary file which contain `REAL*4` datatype from fortran (I believe fortfran 77).
I found this from the [fortran language reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007365fe9/index.html):

> A REAL element has a sign bit, an 8-bit exponent, and a 23-bit fraction. These REAL elements in f77 conform to the IEEE standard.

Though, trying to apply the IEEE standard i get this decimal value `-6.37774515152`, which is incorrect. I've been experimenting with big/little-endian and 64-bit. I also tried every offset in my binary data to make sure I wasn't looking at the wrong place, but no luck (closest I could get was still `0.011872760951519054` of, which I believe would be much larger than a precision error).

UPDATE: I'm sorry if this was unclear: I don't have the original fortran code that generated the binary file.

Some extra information that might be helpful:

- The code is about 20 years old.
- From code in the same project I found mentions of conversion between IEEE and microsoft binary format.
- I also found mentions of REAL*4 which should be an alias for REAL according to the language reference.
- I have successfully decoded the type INTEGER and INTEGER*2 from the same file. The INTEGER type is an 8-bit integer. The INTEGER*2 type is an 16-bit integer with little endianness. Could this be a hint that the REAL*4 is also little endian?
- As pointed out in the comments the reference linked above is to a compiler for fortran, and we can't be sure that the code that generated the binary used the same compiler. Therefore it's possible that the REAL*4 type isn't using the IEEE standard at all.

Comment: Well, there are a few important details needed.  Is it big or little endian?  Also how was the file created (i.e, direct access or stream access)?  This is important in that you may have record markers that can complicate reading the file.  The number `0.0736327171325684` has too many digits for a single precision number.  The trailing 6 or 7 digits are likely garbage.  Have you set a `REAL*4` (note, invalid Fortran type, but I digress) variable to `0.073....` and printed the value with a `B32.32` format?  It is informative.

Comment: Your "language reference" is **only** a reference for that particular compiler by Oracle. Be aware that, depending on the age of the data, some unknown data could come from old computers where the Fortran compiler used a different floating point format. The Fortran standard does not require that the IEEE standard be used even though it is very common in this century.

Comment: The Fortran language says nothing about `REAL*4` or what IEEE-754 compliance the default real type has.  The documentation you link refers to one compiler's implementation: if you aren't using that compiler on that system what it says is not useful.  Please show us detail on what Fortran was used to generate the data you get (until that point, I don't see this as a Fortran question, hence the tag removal).

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for the insight about the compiler. I believe that might be the case considering I've had no luck with brute forcing the entire file with IEEE-754 tests. I updated the post with some extra information.

Comment: @steve I don't know if it's big or little endian, but I found other values in the same file that are little endian, updated the post with that info. I don't know how the file was created. Since I don't know what fortran compiler was used I can't convert the decimal value to a binary value with the same format of the originally generated file.

Comment: The mystery is explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Binary_Format. See my detailed answer below for the full workout. Quite an exercise in reverse-engineering!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite an exercise in reverse-engineering. It appears your number is in little-endian, and it's stored in the so-called Microsoft binary format. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Binary_Format), this format first stores the 8-bit exponent, with a bias of 128; then 1-bit sign, and then the 23-bit significand, with an implicit 1. If the exponent is 0, the number itself represents 0. The binary point is assumed to be before the entire significand. This format does *not* have representations for infinity or NaN values, nor it supports subnormals.

Let's follow this description. The input you have is

```
11000000110011000001011001111101
```

which, in HEX is:

```
C0 CC 16 7D
```

Converting from little-endian, the bit pattern is:

```
7D 16 CC C0
```

Back to binary, and laid out in the 8-1-23 formation, we get:

```
01111101 0 00101101100110011000000
```

The value of the stored exponent is 0b01111101, which is 125 in decimal. The bias in this format is 128; so we have an exponent value of `-3`.

The sign is `0`, so it's a positive number.

The significand has an implicit one, and the radix point is assumed to be before the whole significand. So it is: `0.100101101100110011000000` in binary. Which corresponds to:

```
2^-1 + 2^-4 + 2^-6 + 2^-7 + 2^-9 + 2^-10 + 2^-13 + 2^-14 + 2^-17 + 2^-18
```

The final value, then, is:

```
2^-3 * (2^-1 + 2^-4 + 2^-6 + 2^-7 + 2^-9 + 2^-10 + 2^-13 + 2^-14 + 2^-17 + 2^-18)
```

which evaluates mathematically (i.e., without any rounding/truncation) to:

```
0.07363271713256836
```

which I believe is the value you were looking for in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly.